# Referencing new Activity in Manifest

Tags: java, android

From what I understood watching the Android tutorial, to reference a new class you need to reference it in the manifest.

Say, I had a class AndroidX and I need to reference it. 
What I have to do is;

```
startActivity(new Intent("thepackage.RANDOMNAME")) ;
```

and reference it `android:name="thepackage.RANDOMNAME"`

I'd think "RANDOMNAME" would be a new folder, but it isn't and I have no idea how it is referenced.

I haven't even seen a file or folder.

What's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".AndroidX"></activity>
```

And to call it with an intent, you'd need:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AndroidX.class");
```

Most people call it like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AndroidX.class);
startActivity(i);
```

I don't know if it'd be a problem the other way or not, but I think this is more readable. Feel free to ask anything you need in the comments.

Comment: I don't get it..this was the way it was referenced
startActivity(new Intent("tutorials.basic.android1.ENTERDETAILSOPT"));

<activity android:name=".Forms"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="tutorials.basic.android1.ENTERDETAILSOPT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
Your way looks better but the intent name is different?

Comment: There are different ways to call intent, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

I've only ever done it this way. That's how the manifest should be laid out (up top) and I call my activities how I posted. I'm sure there are other ways it can be done, but I find this the most readable for me.

Comment: I think so too...thanks for the tip man. I have covered a good bit today. Thanks!